# Site logo display is low quality

Tags: files

My site logo looks pixelated even though the image has been sized exactly. When I open the image url in a separate window, the quality is as per expected, however, the display on the site is low quality. Is there any settings I should be tweaking in Drupal?

Comment: Clean browser cache and restart it - sounds like old cache problems.

Comment: Go to **admin/config/media/image-toolkit** set the image quality there and then clear the cache. This is the only setting you can change the quality of the image.

Comment: But the image I'm using is a png file. The image quality setting there seems to be for jpg only.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error, I realised that as long as the image goes through processing by Drupal, it's resolution somehow deteriorates during the process. As the issue with the site logo was a client complaint, I chose to bypass Drupal processing altogether by replacing site logo with site title, then applying text-indent: -9999px and background: url("../logo-image.png") to render the logo instead.